# Running sshfs fusermount after unshare -r

Tags: linux, namespaces, fuse, chroot, sshfs

We have sshfs installed and working so we can mount a remote directory with the command

`sshfs user@remotemachine:dir mount_location`

however if we try using this same working command after running an `unshare -r` we get the error:

`fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted`.

What could we do to run the sshfs mount after the unshare without it failing?

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: No we did not solve this specific problem, but we rethought our structure to avoid it. Instead of using the unshare and some other commands to isolate environments we switched to use docker containers as a replacement and are able to use sshfs from within them fine.